# django-rest-auth encoding email/username

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am running in a issue of UPDATING the extended user profile in django-rest-auth library 
 ( here is the library http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html )

I extended the User with UserProfile:

```
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofile') 
       platformLanguage = models.TextField(null=True)
       mentorApprovalRequest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       approvedAsMentor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       fullName = models.TextField(null=True)
       dateOfBirth = models.DateField(null=True)
       placeOfBirth = models.TextField(null=True)
       bio = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Basically I am creating the initial User which consists of (username, email, password), see the attached pic: [Registration of User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9tki.png)

And then I am trying to update the information of the userProfile, see the pic for update: [Userprofile Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV1xT.png)

And here we go, when I try to update it says, "Not found", but the user was registered. And then when I look at the email decoding instead of admin@gmail.com, I have the wrong email decoding admin%40gmail.com, I guess this might be the issue why I cannot update the details of the userprofile.

Comment: Could you please show your `urls.py` file with /userprofiles/ path?

Comment: I would doublecheck if URL is defined correctly. Did you override it to use slug instead if ID? Try accessing `/userprofiles/admin%40gmail.com/` and see if it returns anything

Comment: @MaximKukhtenkov here it is, the urls.py: https://imgur.com/a/7Wb4i

Comment: it would be nice if you shared your code or GitHub profile, it would help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided urls.py the issue seems to be in the URL, which the info is sent to: by default viewsets would form URL with `pk` parameter, which is incremental Django database ID, so the URL would probably look something like `/userprofiles/<pk>/` where `pk` is numeric User or UserProfile ID (depending on which model is used for the viewset) instead of email slug.